# Is it possible to update the Eclipse RCP application with new Eclipse using RCP Updatesite

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

My Eclipse RCP application has been developed using eclipse-4 Mars.I wanted to update RCP application with Eclipse Neon using RCP update site.Is it possible in eclipse -4 to update the RCP application which is developed using Mars to Eclipse Neon using update site?

Comment: If you included the p2 provisioning system in the RCP you can do this - see [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseP2Update/article.html). Otherwise you can't.

Comment: @greg-449.Thank you so much.It's working and getting updated to new eclipse..:)

Comment: @greg-449: Dear gred, did you follow vogella's guide? I encountered the same issue as this guy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906455/update-eclipse-e4-application-using-p2. Can you help us?

Comment: @aviit No I don't use p2 myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `p2` mechanism in building your application and updating your application, you can do that by  adjusting your target. As mentioned by greg in comment you can refer to that tutorial. Which will give you more idea.